# Data structure work like a Map but allow random changes of keys order

Tags: java, list, data-structures, dictionary

I've read a lot of topics about data structure implementing both `Map` and `List` interface.
And everywhere LinkedHashMap or SortedMap was enough.

But my case is slightly different, because i need not only to keep insertion order of keys or sort map, but perform random changes of keys order.

`List` allow do that using method `add(int index, E element)`, but no implementation of `Map` does not support method like this.
It should be mentioned, that data structure I need will be primarily used as a map.
For example map looks like this:

1. key 1 -> value 1
2. key 2 -> value 2
3. key 3 -> value 3
4. key 4 -> value 4

I may need to move i-th pair to j-th position, dependent on user action:

1. key 1 -> value 1
2. key 4 -> value 4 [j]
3. key 3 -> value 3
4. key 2 -> value 2 [i]

I have an idea to combine LinkedList and HashMap and synchronize insertions and removals between them. So Map can store elements in any order, at the same time elements in List can be ordered as I want. 

But I decided it isn't good. Such structure requires near double amount of memory and badly integrates in Collection Framework, because names collision prevent implementation both List and Map by single class.

So my question is: what is the best way to implement data structure with described features in Java?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want a key to change order?

Comment: HashMap doesn't have a notion of key order; you need LinkedHashMap to maintain insertion order or TreeMap to enforce the natural ordering of keys.  My point is that Map doesn't always have a notion of key ordering.

Comment: If you keep changing the nodes' positions, how will the Map compute (find) every a efficiently? I may be wrong, but with such constraints, the Map would have to go over the whole list (thus O(n) complexity - a list's complexity) to find a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need both O(1) lookups for key-value mappings, and a customizeable sort order that doesn't support immutability like SortedMap and what not, you can just create a wrapper class that uses a Map and a List, like so:

```
    class MapList {
        Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,V>();
        List<K> keysList = new ArrayList<K>();

        public void put(K key, V val) {
            if (!map.contains(key)) {
                keysList.add(key);
            }
            map.put(key, val);
        }

        public void swap(int key1pos, int key2pos) {
            keysList.set(key1pos, keysList.set(key2pos, keysList.get(key1po)));
        }

        // Getter methods, size, etc...
    }
```

I don't think you can get around the need for a custom class with a set of requirements like this.  Keys are generally supposed to be immutable in collection APIs

Comment: I just edit question and described similar solution. And to my mind it isn't good. But if nobody knows better way, I will stop on it.

Comment: It is a good enough solution. It generates a O(n) space overhead (the array from ArrayList), but it is small. I don't think it can get better than this without creating a whole new hashing algorithm/data structure.

Answer (score 0):

If ordering is important, how about create a generic key object class with a order field on it, eg:

```
public class MyKey<K> implements Comparable {
  private int order;
  private K key;
  /* getters & setters */
  /* compareTo() */
}
```

The `compareTo()` method orders by order field value. Then put this to wrap around your key type. Eg: if you're storing a Integer -> Integer map:

```
Map<MyKey<Integer>,Integer> myMap = /*.. */;
```

Then anytime you need to reorder your key, just change the order field value. You can then obtain a sorted key set using map `keySet()` plus `Collections.sort()` or `TreeSet`

This is not by any mean an efficient solution -- but maybe it serves your purpose

Comment: How can the treeset find the object in the tree if you go behind its back and change the ordering? It no longer satisfies the binary search tree requirement.

Comment: I was thinking using the TreeSet only for sorting the key by its order field, not for permanent storage